# Adding search by different criteria in c#

Tags: c#, .net, search

I want to know how to see whether the user selected doctor name or doctor special in the combobox, if the user selects doctor name from the combobox then the first if condition should run, but if the user enters doctor special the second should run. But when i enter doctor name it doesnt work.

```
   if (comboxBox1.Text = "Doctor name") ; 

                {
                    try
                    {
                        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\\dev\\assignt_soft\\healthline_\\healthline_\\healthline_db.accdb");
                        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("select * from doctorss where uuname='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        con.Open();
                        dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader());
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        con.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show("Displaying doctors with the search criteria doctor name");
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }


                    if (comboxBox1.Text = "Doctor special") ; 

                {
                    try
                    {
                        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\\dev\\assignt_soft\\healthline_\\healthline_\\healthline_db.accdb");
                        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("select * from doctorss where doctor special='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        con.Open();
                        dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader());
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        con.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show("Displaying doctors with the search criteria doctor name");
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Start with if (comboxBox1.Text != "Doctor special") and get the rest of the syntax correct.

Comment: and use parameterized sql to prevent sql injection

Comment: @Steve I feel you are going way too far :)

Comment: @ArghyaC well...I don't think so. Everyone should know the danger of sql injection and prevent it

Comment: @ArghyaC thank you very much, it worked perfectly. but then both the if conditions are running, is there a way if the first condition is right then that search is displayed without going to the other?

Comment: @andrew see if the answer helps.

Comment: @andrew your code has a lot of problems: The comparisong operator in C# is == not a single =, the if statement followed by a semicolon ends the expression, the block following the if is always executed. In a query, if you have a field with spaces you need to put square brakets around that field. Now we could start to talk about Sql Injection or simply discuss what happens if your doctor name contains a single quote (O'Reilly) for example.

Comment: @Steve thank you very much, i will search for parameters and make sure my code doesn't get sql injections, as i am sort of learning still, your knowledge means alot to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to format your code like this.

```
try
{
    if (comboxBox1.Text != "Doctor special")
    {
        //doctor name code...       
    }
    else
    {
        //special doctor code...
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

For `if` statements, always use `==` equality operator in C#, like `if (count == 0)`. Single equal sign is used for assignment like `int count = 1`. And no `;` after if(...), it will make the compiler think there is a blank statement, and associate that with the if condition. The block following that will become a normal code block and will execute always!

First get this working. Then, make your queries parameterized to minimize sql injection threat as @Steve mentioned in the comment. Refer [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I made the code this way, thank you very much. my code  is working perfectly now, i will learn parameters and make my code much more perfect and powerful. thank you once again @Arghya C

Comment: @andrew Glad that your code worked and got ideas about common mistakes in coding. #SOreadytohelp  :)